# Need some assistance in IF function

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to build a webpage about a football team.

So, I put info in a sql file, and then in xampp database. The problem is, when I put info for players and coaches like this:https://i.stack.imgur.com/8a16u.png they appear in the section of 'Stores' and 'Trophies' too which makes it look like annoying :P
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdwKJ.png

So I need a code like IF market value or Position or Place of birth = empty, then to hide those values (I mean to hide the: market value, position etc) I know that I must use the IF function in the functions file. I tried something but didn't work actually.

what is the exact code that I must use and where should I put it?

The functions file is here:

```
    <?php

//Position:    
//function to generate the local navigation bar for the bookstore web application

function gen_navigation(){
include("dbconnect.php");
echo "<head>";
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/navigation.css" />';
echo "</head>";
$query="select * from categories";
$result=mysql_query($query);
echo "<div id=navcontainer>";
echo "<ul id=navlist>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<li>";
echo "<a href=items.php?categoryid=";
echo $row['categoryid'];
echo ">";
echo $row['name'];
echo "</a>";
echo "</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
echo "</div>";
mysql_close();

}

//Position:    
//function to display the new items. The layout is formated by using tables

//position:    
//function to display the new items. The layout is formated by using tables
function showbooksbycat($categoryid=1,$offset=0,$limit=8){
if(empty($offset)){
    $offset=0;
    }
include("dbconnect.php");
$query="select * from items where categoryid=$categoryid order by isbn limit $offset,$limit";

$result=mysql_query($query);

echo "<br>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<table width=100% border=0>";
echo "<tr class=newitems>";
echo "<th>";
    echo "Market Value".$row['market value'];
    echo "</th>";
    echo "<th>";
        echo $row['name'];
        echo "</th>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td width=100>";
    echo "<img src=pictures/".$row['picture'].">";
    echo "</td>";
        echo "<td align=left>";
    echo "<p class=itemmaininf>";
echo "<b>Name:</b> ".$row['name']."<br>";
echo "<b>Position:</b> ".$row['position']."<br>";
echo "<b>Place Of Birth:</b> ".$row['birthplace']."<br>";
  echo "<b>Date Of Birth:</b> ".$row['date']."<br>";

echo "<b>Previous Clubs:</b> ".$row['previous clubs']."<br>";
echo "</p>";
        echo "<p class=footitem>";
    echo "</p>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
 echo "</table>";
echo "<br>";
}
mysql_close();
}


function nav($categoryid=1,$offset=0,$limit=8){
include("dbconnect.php");
$query="select * from items where categoryid=$categoryid";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($result);



echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";

if($offset>0){

echo "<a href=items.php?categoryid=".$categoryid."&offset=".($offset-$limit);
echo ">";
echo "<img border=0 src=pictures/prev.gif></a>";
echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";

}

if($offset+$limit<$numrows){
echo "<a href=items.php?categoryid=".$categoryid."&offset=".($offset+$limit);
echo ">";
echo "<img border=0 src=pictures/next.gif></a>";
}
echo "</font>";
}
?>
```

Comment: you don't need one echo for each line.

Comment: You `tried something but it didn't work actually`. What might that something be...? Better to learn what you're doing wrong then just have someone give you the answer...

Comment: `so i need a code like IF market value or Position or Place of birth = empty,` and yet there's nothing like that in the code you posted, so all of this code is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: try to add 2-3 line breaks after each code line, it will not help, but your eyes will start bleeding the same as mine now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the basic approach is

change

```
 echo "<b>Place Of Birth:</b> ".$row['birthplace']."<br>";
```

to

```
if(!empty($row['birthplace'])){ //! is not, so this says not empty
    echo "<b>Place Of Birth:</b> ".$row['birthplace']."<br>";
}
```

Comment: omg man i love you :D, it worked, and now it looks SuperCool :D
BIG THANKS!
im sorry about the code in the description i put space in every line cus it didn't let me upload it, but now i fixed it, hope it looks better and don't damage your eyes and mine too :)
again THANK YOU! :D